# Hyperopt set timeouts and modify space during execution

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

if someone can help on:

1. How to set a timeout for each individual test ? a timeout for the total experiment ?
2. How to setup a progressive strategy which would eliminate/prune a % of worst scoring branches of search space at different stage of the experiment (while using current optimization algorithms) ? ie. at 30% of the max total experiment, it could remove 50% of the worst scoring classifiers and all its branch of hyperparameters to remove it from upcoming tests. Then, same process at 60%...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following my exchange on hyperopt's github:

1. there is not a per-trial timeout but hyperopt-sklearn implements its own solution by just wrapping the function. Please look for "fn_with_timeout" at https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt-sklearn/ .
2. from issue 210: "the optimizers are stateless, and fmin stores all state of the experiment in the trials object. So if you remove some experiments from the trials object, it's as if they never happened. use fmin's "max_evals" parameter to interrupt search as often as you need to make these sorts of modifications. It should be fine to use repeated calls with e.g. max_evals increasing by 1 every time if you want really fine grained control."

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for looking into this, @doxav. I've written some code that addresses question 1, taking part of `fn_with_timeout` from `hyperopt-sklearn` and adapting it for standard Hyperopt cost functions.

You can find it here:
https://gist.github.com/hunse/247d91d14aaa8f32b24533767353e35d

Answer (score 0):

To set a timeout for the whole experiment you can use the timeout parameter if you are using Spark Trials as mentioned [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/_extras/notebooks/source/hyperopt-spark-mlflow.html). The documentation says "timeout: Maximum time (in seconds) that fmin() can run. The default is no maximum time limit."

```
from hyperopt import SparkTrials  
trials = SparkTrials(parallelism = 20, timeout= 1800)
```

now use the trials in the run:

```
 with mlflow.start_run():
   argmin = fmin(
    fn=objective,
    space=search_space,
    algo=algo,
    max_evals=160,
    trials=trials)
```